# How to use create 2 Array with User input with Std.readAllInts()

Tags: java, arrays, input

This is how it should work, i Put in put for the 1 st array like: 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 then 2 and 3 are row and colum and the rest are the values. Problem is the 1st array work, but when i reach EOF ( ctrl+z) then there is out of bound exception. Which mean i cant input value for the 2nd Array like the 1st one. I know there is anotherway where  that i can declare array size first then value. But how could i fix this f i still want to usr StdIn.readAllInts() ?

```
public class MatrixMult {
public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("First Matrix Config");
    int[] einGabeMatrix1= StdIn.readAllInts();  
    int zeileM1 = einGabeMatrix1[0];
    int spalteM1 = einGabeMatrix1[1];
    int[][] ersteMatrix= new int [zeileM1][spalteM1];
    int k=2;
    int sum;
    for(int i=0;i<zeileM1-1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<spalteM1-1;j++){
            ersteMatrix[i][j]=einGabeMatrix1[k];
            k++;
        }
    }


    System.out.println("Second Matrix Config");
    int[] einGabeMatrix2 = StdIn.readAllInts();
    int zeileM2 = einGabeMatrix2[0];
    int spalteM2 = einGabeMatrix2[1];
    int h=2;
    int[][] zweiteMatrix= new int [zeileM2][spalteM2];
    for(int m=0;m<zeileM2-1;m++){
        for(int n=0;n<spalteM2-1;n++){
            zweiteMatrix[m][n]=einGabeMatrix2[h];
            h++;
        }
    }  

    int[][] ergebnisMatrix= new int [zeileM1][spalteM2];
    for (int t = 0; t < zeileM1; t++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < spalteM2; c++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int d = 0; d < spalteM1; d++) {
                sum = sum + ersteMatrix[t][d] * zweiteMatrix[d][c];
            }
            ergebnisMatrix[t][c] = sum;
        }
    }   

    for(int i=0;i<zeileM1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<spalteM1;j++){
                System.out.println(ergebnisMatrix[i][j]);
            }
        }

}
```

}
// This is StdIn.readAllInts(), standard method by java.

```
public static int[] readAllInts() {
    String[] fields = readAllStrings();
    int[] vals = new int[fields.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        vals[i] = Integer.parseInt(fields[i]);
    return vals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is coming from the fact that `StdIn.readAllInts()` reads until the EOF.  There will be no values left to read by the time your code gets to the second call.

I would suggest instead using the `StdIn.readInt()` call to read each integer one at a time and then you can use it within your loop to read the exact number of values your need.

Here is an example of how you could get the first 2 integers to find your matrix size:

```
int zeileM1 = StdIn.readInt();
int spalteM1 = StdIn.readInt();
```

You will also need to apply this method in your for loops to read the data into the matrix.

Comment: yes but i will have to determine which size of matrix i want to get first, but i want to put the size and the value together as 1 array then choose the first two index as the size.

Comment: You should still be able to submit all the values at once to standard input even if the code only reads them one at a time.  The issue with readAllInts() is that it does not stop reading until it reaches EOF from standard input which means there will be nothing left for the next call.  Alternatively you could use just the first call and parse the second matrix where k left off: 
int zeileM2 = einGabeMatrix1[k++];
int spalteM2 = einGabeMatrix1[k++];